# Difference between embedded and embedded-systems tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

I looked through the recent questions in the [embedded](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embedded) tag, and they seem to be primarily about embedded systems, with some exceptions, like [What is the difference between embedding and composing?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/275267/76821).

Is there any difference with the [embedded-systems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embedded-systems) tag, and if not, could they be merged?

Comment: These tags do not have a lot of questions. I am looking through them to prune the low-hanging fruit, then I will reevaluate and post an answer. I am leaning toward merging them, but we may need a moderator to do it because so few active users are active enough in those tags.

Comment: I just merged into [tag:embedded-systems]. There's some clean-up and retagging that needs to be done, but there are only 100 questions. Most appear to be proper use of the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through it, it looks like most [embedded](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embedded) and [embedded-systems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embedded-systems) questions are about embedded systems. There are few enough questions that a manual cleanup can be done after a merge.

I'm just thinking about what tag should be preferred. I think I'd prefer [embedded-systems](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/embedded-systems), even though it's half the size. I think the tag is more descriptive and more in line with how people may be searching for questions. I'd just like some kind of confirmation on the direction of the merge before I go ahead and do it.

Comment: I have been looking through them and cleaning up some of the off-topic and mis-tagged questions, and I agree they should probably be merged and that [tag:embedded-systems] is more descriptive.

Comment: I too think [tag:embedded-systems] would be better. It's less confusing (see e.g. the question I linked to about embedding and composing) for new askers.

Comment: Close enough to consensus to me. I'll merge right now and clean up on my lunch break.

Comment: @CamilStaps questions like that should be retagged. I know you do not have the rep to do this, but Thomas and I (and whoever else wants to help) will take care of it. Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: @Snowman I know, but I mean for new questions. A tag like embedded-systems would never be added to someone posting a new question about embedding and composing, but  a tag like embedded may. Thanks for cleaning it up!

Comment: @CamilStaps Thomas just merged the tags, which I think satisfies the issue you brought up in your question.